# Calculating numbers with vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am really new to vueJS.

I try to get two input value, adding them together, and show the result. I found it is really wired, because when number1 minus number3, or number1 multiplied number2, or number1 divided number2, the calculating is all working fine. However when number1 plus number2, it doesn’t working, and seems add two str together (for example: 1 + 2 = 12).

What’s going on here? And how can I get result with number1 + number2

Please help

```html
    <div id="app">

            <input type="number" name="number1" v-on:input= "update_number1">
            <p>{{ number1 }}</p>
            <input type="number" name="number2" v-on:input= "update_number2">
            <p>{{ number2 }}</p>

            <hr>
            <p>{{ result() }}</p>

    </div>
```

```
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        number1: 0,
        number2: 0,
      },
      methods: {
        update_number1: function (event) {
          this.number1 = event.target.value;
        },
        update_number2: function (event) {
          this.number2 = event.target.value;
        },
        result: function () {
    
          return this.number1 + this.number2;
        },
    
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is more likely a javascript problem than a vue one.

If you want to add two numbers, you can use `parseInt()` function as:

```
result: function () {
  return parseInt(this.number1) + parseInt(this.number2);
}
```

Comment: But I didn't understand why - / * is working, but not + ?

Comment: Because the `+` can also be used to concatenate strings, so by default it assumes you want to concatenate strings when you do `'1' + 1` but for multiplication it only has 1 use, so js knows you want to multiply

Comment: HA..I see.. Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks Chief, you saved the day. I did parseInt(this.number1 + this.Number2)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the updated fiddle below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    number1: 0,
    number2: 0,
  },
  computed: {
    result() {
        return parseInt(this.number1) + parseInt(this.number2);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
            <input type="number" name="number1" v-model="number1">
            <p>{{ number1 }}</p>
            <input type="number" name="number2" v-model="number2">
            <p>{{ number2 }}</p>
            <hr>
            <p>{{ result }}</p>
</div>
```

**What did we change?**:

- We bound `number1` and `number2` to the inputs using [`v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html), that way they are reactive to changes in the input fields.
- We changed `result` to a [`computed`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) property.
- We parsed `number1` and `number2` to `Integers` to that they always return number values.
- We removed the `()` from the template so that `results()` became `result`.

Please let me know if you have any questions or don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

This code works :)

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
        firstNum: 0,
        secondNum: 0,
    },
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  First Number
  <input type="text" v-on:input="firstNum = parseFloat($event.target.value)"/>
  Second Number
  <input type="text" v-on:input="secondNum = parseFloat($event.target.value)"/>

  Result 
  <h1><span style="color: red">{{firstNum + secondNum}}</span></h1>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
<div>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Cecherz. This is what I have been looking for. I also bound the values to their respective input fields using the v-model.